# Exception during handling of messages Unrecognized advice action handshake

Tags: lightning, salesforce1-app, salesforce-id, service-cloud-console, omnichannel

I am getting following error message while using cometd library "Exception during handling of messages Unrecognized advice action handshake". The thing which I want to achieve is listening of platform events using this library in lightning.

It was working till last month but now tester reported that its not working and when I investigated, found the above mentioned error message.Has anyone else encountered the same issue.

In notification settings both "Enable in-app notifications" and "Enable push notifications checkboxes" are unchecked as per the suggestion in trailhead for this issue.
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/projects/workshop-platform-events/steps/platform-event-subscribe#testtheinstantnotificationapp

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue following the workshop platform events from Trailhead. I never got it to work reliably. But I have found out that Salesforce has recently released an new API for working with event messages in a Lightning Component. I's much simpler to setup and works well.

See: 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:empApi/documentation